# Extracting rows from df based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I have a df which I have ordered:

```
df1 = df[with(df, order(ID, Admission)), ]
```

df1 is outlined below:

```
df1

ID        Admission     Op1   
001122a   2010-01-25    GHJ12
001122a   2011-02-14    GHJ12
002233b   2011-01-27    GHJ12
002233b   2011-05-13    GHJ14
003344c   2010-06-01    GHJ12
003344c   2010-12-01    GHJ14
003344c   2011-03-27    GHJ12
```

Is there a way to subset/extract rows in this scenario to obtain the earliest $Admission for each specific $ID, or would I have to use loops for this? I would want to obtain df2 below:

```
df2

ID        Admission     Op1   
001122a   2010-02-14    GHJ12
002233b   2011-01-27    GHJ12
003344c   2010-06-01    GHJ12
```

I realise this may be a trivial question but I have searched and can't find anything specific enough to apply to this scenario.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ddply` from `plyr` :

```
 ddply(df1,.(ID),function(x)x[which.max(as.Date(x$Admission)),])
     ID  Admission   Op1
1 001122a 2011-02-14 GHJ12
2 002233b 2011-05-13 GHJ14
3 003344c 2011-03-27 GHJ12
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
DT = data.table(df1,key='ID')
DT[,{
          ii <- which.max(as.Date(Admission))
          list(Admission= Admission[ii], Op1=Op1[ii]) },
       by =ID]
        ID  Admission   Op1
1: 001122a 2011-02-14 GHJ12
2: 002233b 2011-05-13 GHJ14
3: 003344c 2011-03-27 GHJ12
```

Comment: @zx8754: you just need to change the `max` to a `min` in the function call.

Comment: Thanks @agstudy, the approach using ddply seemed to work nicely substituting the which.max for which.min

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `merge` and `aggregate`

```
> df1$Admission <- as.Date(df1$Admission, format="%Y-%m-%d")
> merge(aggregate(Admission ~ ID, max, data=df1), df1)
       ID  Admission   Op1
1 001122a 2011-02-14 GHJ12
2 002233b 2011-05-13 GHJ14  # maybe your example has an error for this row.
3 003344c 2011-03-27 GHJ12
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jilber. This didn't quite do what I wanted. This still returned duplicate IDs. I may be going wrong somewhere, however.

Answer (score 2):

Since your dataset is ordered, it's very easy. Just remove rows including duplicated values of `ID`:

```
df1[!duplicated(df1$ID), ]

#        ID  Admission   Op1
# 1 001122a 2010-01-25 GHJ12
# 3 002233b 2011-01-27 GHJ12
# 5 003344c 2010-06-01 GHJ12
```