# Remove data from DF based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, filter

I have a large data frame (df) that looks something like the following sample. There are a number of data entry errors in the data set and I need to remove these. In the sample data all NSW States should have a Postcode starting with 2. All VIC States should have a Postcode starting with 3.

```
| Suburb | State | Postcode |
| ------ | ----- | -------- |
| FLEMINGTON | NSW | 2140 |
| FLEMINGTON | NSW | 2144 |
| FLEMINGTON | NSW | 3996 |
| FLEMINGTON | VIC | 2996 |
| FLEMINGTON | VIC | 3021 |
| FLEMINGTON | VIC | 3031 |
```

I need the final table to look like...

```
| Suburb | State | Postcode |
| ------ | ----- | -------- |
| FLEMINGTON | NSW | 2140 |
| FLEMINGTON | NSW | 2144 |
| FLEMINGTON | VIC | 3021 |
| FLEMINGTON | VIC | 3031 |
```

The following solution is kind of close, but I don't know how to filter for integers starting with a specific number and am under time pressure.

[Extracting rows from df based on multiple conditions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905685/extracting-rows-from-df-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-r)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this easily extended on, do it as a merge operation against only your acceptable values for each state:

```
merge(
  transform(dat, Pc1=substr(Postcode,1,1)),
  data.frame(State=c("NSW","VIC"),Pc1=c("2","3"))
)

#  State Pc1     Suburb Postcode
#1   NSW   2 FLEMINGTON     2140
#2   NSW   2 FLEMINGTON     2144
#3   VIC   3 FLEMINGTON     3021
#4   VIC   3 FLEMINGTON     3031
```

Comment: Works like a dream. :)

Comment: Or another option by counting the frequency `setDT(df)[,  N := .N,.(substr(Postcode, 1, 1), State)][, .SD[N == max(N)], State][, N := NULL][]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this? If your Postcode are integers & these are the only conditions, it should be pretty straightforward:

```
df <- data.frame(Suburb = rep("FLEMINGTON", 6),
                 State = c(rep("NSW", 3), rep("VIC", 3)),
                 Postcode = c(2140,2144,3996,2996,3021,3031))

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  filter((State == "NSW" & Postcode < 3000) | (State == "VIC" & Postcode >= 3000))

> df
      Suburb State Postcode
1 FLEMINGTON   NSW     2140
2 FLEMINGTON   NSW     2144
3 FLEMINGTON   VIC     3021
4 FLEMINGTON   VIC     3031
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There are a number of combinations beyond those in the example, hence the accepted solution works best in this instance. :)